# ReactJs - Why does calling onDelete() with parantheses without an arrow function not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Currently learning React, and I am confused as to why this acts the way it does.
My App.JS:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header'
import Tasks from './components/Tasks'
import {useState} from 'react'


function App() {
  let name = "Max";
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Doctors Appointment',
        day: "Feb 5th at 2:30 pm",
        reminder: true,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Meeting at School",
        day: "Feb 6th at 1:30pm",
        reminder: true,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Food Shopping",
        day: "Feb 5th at 2:30pm",
        reminder: false,
    },
  ])
  const deleteTask = (id) => {
    alert("deleted " + id);
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete = {deleteTask} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Tasks.JS basically just displays Task.js as h3s
Task.js:

```
import {FaTimes} from 'react-icons/fa'

const Task = ({ task, onDelete }) => {
    return (
        <div className = "task">
            <h3>{task.text} <FaTimes style = {{color:'red', cursor:"pointer"}} onClick = {() => onDelete(task.id)}/></h3>
            <p>{task.day}</p>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Task
```

So I saw the arrow function for `onClick = () => onDelete(task.id)` and wondered why I couldn't just do `onClick = onDelete(task.id)` So I tried that and got some unexpected behavior. Basically, upon the page creation i got the alert that each item had been deleted thrice, and then afterwards nothing happened when I clicked it.
Why does this happen? Like how do I explain this behavior? Why is this arrow function needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use `onClick = onDelete(task.id)` it will call `onDelete` on every render of that component.  You're passing the return from that function to `onClick`.  By using the arrow function, you're passing the function itself, so that when a user clicks on your `h3`, it will then and only then call that function.

Note - not a great idea to put `onClicks` on elements like `h3`s for accessibility reasons.

Comment: So, the arrow function is also just a function right? So when passing it into onClick it's return value is given right? So that means it calls onDelete right? I guess my question is, why does the arrow fuction work differently than the non arrow function here? I don't fully get that. Like your are passing in the function itself but that function is just a call to another one right?

Comment: Correct.  The arrow function is just wrapping your `onDelete` with another function so it can be called on demand instead of being called inline.